# How to display citations in tex grouped as [1]-[3] in stead of [1,2,3] in beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am giving a presentation in the beamer class. I would like the grouped bibliographic references to be displayed as [1]-[3] instead of [1-3].

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

%\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    References \cite{rodrigues2016unbalanced, rodrigues2016considerations, monteiro2018unbalanced}.
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \tiny
    
    \bibliographystyle{mmc-unsrt}
    \bibliography{my_bibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried to include the `\renewcommand\citepunct{], [}` and
`\renewcommand\citedash{]-[}` commands in the preamble but it didn't work. They worked in the article class but in the beamer they don't work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you very much! This solution worked perfectly. I had tried it with `natbib` but it didn't work, but the modified version presented in the answer worked!